# Remove App from managed package

Tags: managed-package, app, release

I have a released managed package which contains App. In new version I added Connected App to this package and wanted to remove old App. Is it possible? At least I would like to remove link to it, because currently there are two after installation:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to the [ISVforce Guide](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf) Available Components section an Application is *Developer Deletable* and *Subscriber Deletable*.

> ## Developer Deletable
>
> A developer can delete some components after the package is uploaded as Managed - Released. Deleted components
>   are not deleted in the subscriber's organization during a package upgrade.
>
> ## Subscriber Deletable
>
> A subscriber or installer of a package can delete the component.

So you and the installer should be able to delete the older App. Worst case you could alter the permissions for the App for each Salesforce profile so they couldn't see the old App.